# Why $(":select").focus does not work while $(":input").focus works?

Tags: jquery, select, focus

I have a JQuery code which does something when input or select elements get focus. 
Although my code for input element works, select element does not work.

Here is what I do.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(":input").focus(function () { //this works
    //do something
   });

   $(":select").focus(function () { //this doesn't
    //do something      
   });
});

</script>
</body>
```

I tried some variation on select, such as using $("select") instead of $(":select"), 
but did not work either.

I am a beginner for JQuery.

I appreciate if you could tell me how I can make it work.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short and simple: Because `:select` does not exist.

[`$('select')` will work](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/6V9py/), but only if you have a `<select>` element in your code. You have not in your above code.

Have a look at the [list of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

[`:input` instead *does* exist](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

---

In general: Selectors starting with a colon `:` are pseudo selectors. They are defined by jQuery (they are not valid CSS selectors) and select elements with a certain state or property).

You already have encountered `:input`. It selects all form control elements. Another one is e.g `: visible`, which selects all displayed (visible) elements.

---

**Update:**

The `<select>` elements have to exists when `$('select').focus(...` is executed. I don't know the software you are using, but if they load the elements e.g. via Ajax, then most likely they don't exist yet when your code is executed.

1. Make sure there are `<select>` elements on the page.
2. You might have to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

   ```
   $('select').live('focus', function() {
       //stuff
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks Felix! Well, when I cleaned up my code and only focused on this function, $("select").focus worked. (your ".live" code also worked) Maybe there was some problem in other parts of my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user605660: Your're welcome :) You use `live()` only if necessary. If the other works: perfect. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a :select selector, but since "select" is its own tag in HTML, you can just use $('select') (like you can use $('body'), for example).  A better approach is probably to assign an "id" to your "select" element, and then use $('#id') to select that element directly.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I thought about using #id, but here, I want this function to be invoked for every select element. So, should $("select") work? Maybe this does not work because I use this code in Qualtrics (online survey tool like a surveyMonkey)..

Answer (score 0):

$(":select") is not a valid selector. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks Rui. Yes, I suspected that. I tried $("select") too, but this did not work. Is this also invalid? What I want is not $(":selected"), I think. (This is more related to options as far as I know) Could you tell me what is valid?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using :input :select alone. This is a performance killer specially if you have allot of elements in your DOM. :input means jQuery must search every elements in your DOM to find inputs. The below selector is allot faster and more efficient.

$('#myform').find('input')

Check performance test (75% faster) http://jsperf.com/input-selector-performance0

So you can basically do

```
$('#myform').delegate('select','focus', function() {
   // what ever you want to do here
});
```

Comment: Do you mean `$('#myform').find(':input')` ? Because `input` and `:input` are different.